# Trying to submit two input fields in an array, not working

Tags: javascript, json, input

Here's my javascript function, that populates input fields for child ages, depending on the number of children input field. Like if the number is children field has a value of 2, then two extra fields are pupolated for the ages. The problem is the only the last on gets submitted:

```
function handleChildrenNoChange() {
    const childrenNo = document.getElementById('childrenNo').value;
    const childAgeFieldsContainer = document.getElementById('childAgeFields');

    // Clear existing child age fields
    childAgeFieldsContainer.innerHTML = '';

    // Add label for child ages
    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerText = 'Gyerekek életkora:';
    childAgeFieldsContainer.appendChild(label);

    // Create FormData object to collect form data
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Generate child age fields based on the selected number of children
    const childAges = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= childrenNo; i++) {
        const ageField = document.createElement('input');
        ageField.type = 'number';
        ageField.placeholder = `Gyermek ${i} életkora`;
        ageField.name = 'chd_age'; // Use the same name for all child age fields
        ageField.required = true;

        // Append age field to the container
        childAgeFieldsContainer.appendChild(ageField);

        // Add event listener to capture the value when the user enters it
        ageField.addEventListener('change', function () {
            // Update the 'chd_age' field in the FormData object
            childAges[i - 1] = ageField.value;
            formData.set('chd_age', childAges.join(','));

            // Debugging: Log the age values after the user enters them
            console.log(`Child ${i} age: ${ageField.value}`);
            console.log('chd_age:', formData.get('chd_age'));
        });
    }
}
```

Then here's the json output where there is only the last one shows:

```
{"client_name_last":"Teszt","client_name_first":"Elek","client_mail":"info@kontrast.com","client_telephone":"6200532947","check_in":"2024-05-01","check_out":"2024-05-02","username":"Pannon","password":"wwere4436jv9RFMPs5vkztx","property_id":"701043","client_lang":"","adults_no":"2","chd_no":"2","chd_age":"21","client_comment":""}
```

And this is what the chd_age part should look like: "chd_age":"13,21"

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `childAges[i - 1] = ageField.value;`: what is `i` when this executes? I would use `childAges.push()` instead of setting the index manually.

Comment: @mykaf `i` is the iteration variable of the `for` loop. It goes from 1 to `childrenNo`, so he subtracts 1 to get the array index.

Comment: @mykaf `push()` would not be correct. This is in a `change` event listener, so every time you changed the child's age it would push the new age without removing the old one. It has to replace just that child's age.

Comment: Do you see the correct result from `console.log('chd_age:', formData.get('chd_age'));`?

Comment: Here's the console log: https://paste.pics/66683038ff9ab3b8d7c1c40c844bd599

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript get a bit convoluted with the event listener for the change event and the formData object (`const formData = ...`) in the middle of the function `handleChildrenNoChange`. Split it up.

Here I place the age input elements in a fieldset. Thereby, it gets easier to find them (`form.children.elements`), add more or remove them. **On purpose** I do not give the input elements for the age input(s) a name. So, when I create the formData object in the submit callback function the input elements for age are **not** included. Then I test if there are input elements in the fieldset and append the age(s) to the formData object if needed.

```js
const form01 = document.forms.form01;

form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  if(form.children.elements.length > 0){
    let ageStr = [...form.children.elements].map(elm => elm.value).join(',');
    formData.append('chd_age', ageStr);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData)));
});

form01.childrenNo.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let num = parseInt(e.target.value);
  let elements = form.children.elements;
  Object.keys([...new Array(num)]).forEach(key => {
    let keyint = parseInt(key);
    if(!elements[keyint]){
      let label = document.createElement('label');
      label.textContent = `Child age:`;
      let input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'number';
      label.appendChild(input);
      form.children.appendChild(label);
    }
  });
  [...elements]
    .filter((elm, i) => i+1 > num)
    .forEach(elm => elm.closest('label').remove());
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>
    <span>First name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="client_name_first">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Children:</span>
    <select name="childrenNo">
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <fieldset name="children"></fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```